# What should be noticed when using numpy.arange method?

Tags: python, numpy

I encountered a question when I wanted to generate a numpy array using numpy.arange. 
For example, I want to generate an array that contains 3862 elements:

```
array1=numpy.arange(3.5678,3.5678+3862*0.0001,0.0001)
```

But the shape of array1 is `(3863,)`. And what made me more confused is this:

```
In:
numpy.arange(3.5678,3.5678+3860*0.0001,0.0001).shape
numpy.arange(3.5678,3.5678+3861*0.0001,0.0001).shape
numpy.arange(3.5678,3.5678+3862*0.0001,0.0001).shape
numpy.arange(3.5678,3.5678+3863*0.0001,0.0001).shape
Out:
(3861,);(3861,);(3863,);(3863,)
```

Why did this happen? Due to the precision?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

*For floating point arguments, the length of the result is ceil((stop - start)/step). Because of floating point overflow, this rule may result in the last element of out being greater than stop.*

And also:

*stop number:
End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.*

You can check out [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655175/python-numpy-arange-strange-behavior) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217178/inconsistent-behavior-in-np-arange) for more detail and info on how to deal with the situation.